# Is the bold part of the following sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

It was naturally assumed the temple was burned down as an anti-revolution symbol in those dark days, but as it turned out, **revealed by the village elders**, it was burned down under much more mysterious circumstances.

I want to express the idea that the fact that the temple was burned down under much more mysterious circumstances was revealed to the narrator by the village elders, but is it grammatically correct to insert the bold part for this purpose into the whole sentence?

Comment: You either keep _as it turned out_ or _as was revealed by the village elders_, depending on the situation of course.

Comment: Put _as_  (or _as was_) in front of _revealed_. That introduces the clause and indicates what kind of clause it is; the participle itself doesn't do that.

Comment: *As it turned out* is an idiom and fairly informal phrasing. I would ditch it and simplify what you're trying to say: *It was naturally assumed that the temple was burned down as an anti-revolution symbol in those dark days. But village elders revealed that it burned down under much more mysterious circumstances.* (Don't use the passive voice in the last clause unless you know that people lit it on fire—as compared to, say, the fire being mysteriously sparked by an angry god.)

Answer (score 2):

That sentence doesn't work as it stands, because there is nothing that "revealed by the village elders" could reasonably be taken to describe.

The following is better:

It was naturally assumed the temple was burned down as an anti-revolution symbol in those dark days, but, as was revealed by the village elders, it was burned down under much more mysterious circumstances.

That version implies that the elders revealed the latter fact. But it doesn't imply more specifically that the elders revealed it specifically to the narrator -- for all we know, they could have let the whole village know.